# Any way to make the start screen transparent?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Is there any way to make the start screen background fully transparent so that it displays my desktop (including everything on my desktop and any open windows)?

Comment: While I can't give a definitive answer, I can say that I highly doubt it - (Formerly) Metro and the classic desktop environment are compartmentalised from each other, so it's quite likely that the Start Screen is entirely unaware of the desktop's current state.

Comment: I suspected that'd be the answer. Really disappointing how the whole feature was implemented in win8

Comment: In Win8.1 at least you can set the Start Screen background to be your Desktop wallpaper. Not quite what you want, but probably the closest you'll get unless some third-party hack manages to achieve this. Edit: Found something; perhaps there's hope after all...

Comment: But it doesn't even allow you to set your desktop background as the start screen background since it forcefully lowers the white point to dim it.

Comment: Just to confirm since the utility I linked to has two sliders, did you try *increasing* the Tile opacity and *decreasing* the Start Screen opacity levels?

Comment: Yes, I was not able to increase transparency of the background while keeping the tiles themselves opaque